# Handling mysql errors when using remote form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a form using :remote => true

```
<%= form_for @expression, url: {controller: "expressions", action: "create"}, :remote => true  do |f| %>

...

<% end %>
```

In my controller code, I am tying to display an alert message to indicate if the form data has been saved or not.

```
def create
    @expression = Expression.new(params[:expression])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @expression.save     
        format.js { render :js => "alert('Expression details have been saved'); window.opener.document.location.reload(true); window.close();" }
      else
        format.js { render :js => "alert('Error. Please ensure that expression patterns are unique');" }
      end

    end

  end
```

The alert message is correctly displayed if the form data has been successfully been saved in the database. However if for some reason (database constraint -- Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry), the data could not be saved, nothing happens. The alert message is not displayed.

Is there a way to handle mysql errors when using remote form?

Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mysql2::Error: Duplicate` is an exception, not an ActiveRecord validation error. You could handle it by catching the exception, I.E:

```
def create
  @expression = Expression.new(params[:expression])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @expression.save     
      format.js { render :js => "alert('Expression details have been saved'); window.opener.document.location.reload(true); window.close();" }
    else
      format.js { render :js => "alert('Error. Please ensure that expression patterns are unique');" }
    end
  end

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :js => "alert('Error..');" }
  end
end
```

My example only catches that specific exception but you can catch any exception with `rescue Exception`

Comment: Lovely..thanks a lot. I have been struggling with this for a while